# Avalondock grouping undocked tabs

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, avalondock

I can't find in the avalon dock forums an answer.  Is there a way to group undocked tabs.  Basicly i'm looking for the same functionality as visual studio tabs. Have anyone done this?

Comment: I Guess no one tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly.

If you mean that you want to dock two free floating/undocked "tabs" in the same window container it is only possible with LayoutAnchorables, not with LayoutDocuments.

I encountered the same issue and it took me quite some time to find that all I had to do was to add the tabs I wanted to dock, while outside the main window, to the Anchorables list.

Not sure if this helps.